# Why is Heroku aborting an SSL handshake but not GitHub?

Tags: git, ssl, networking, heroku

I am having an issue with pushing to Heroku:

`➜  git push heroku ******
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/****.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake`

However, if I push the same code to GitHub (a private repo), it goes through no problem:

`➜  git push origin *****
Counting objects: 455, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (216/216), done.
Writing objects: 100% (455/455), 1.35 MiB | 232.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 455 (delta 367), reused 302 (delta 234)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (367/367), completed with 82 local objects.
To github.com:***/***.git
   278516b5..ed34f009  master -> master`

I have a couple questions:

1.) How do I diagnose this issue to get more details?
2.) What might be happening on my end or Heroku's end that it aborts the SSL handshake?

Note this issue only occurs when I'm on HughesNet satellite internet on BOTH my computers -- my laptop & PC. If I change to a different network, the push happens just fine.

Comment: Well, start network sniffer like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), gather network traces for bad push from current network and for good push for different network, then filter non-relevant traffic and check the difference in networking. Also check, which exactly SSL handshake step fails and what is the error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openssl s_client -connect git.heroku.com:443 -servername git.heroku.com
```

^ should tell you a little more about what's going on. Else you'll pretty much have to inspect the ClientHello and ServerHello exchange, just like @nnovich-OK mentioned ([this link may help)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html). Brace yourself for some serious detective work.

There's not much you can really do other than speak to your satellite ISP and ask them to take a look at the handshake capture. Maybe it's just an MTU issue (although i highly doubt it)? Sattelite links are very speshul though, anything goes.